# What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse on windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, 64-bit

What's the best settings for Eclipse 3.5.2 on Windows 7 64 bit? I've read [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse), but nowhere 64 bit system was mentioned. Eclipse 3.5.2 runs pretty slow on my 8GB windows 7 64 bit box.
Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: Good point. I will address that in my next answer in that same "best JVM" question for eclipse3.6 Helios ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've had to use [compressed oops](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) when running eclipse on 64 bit operating systems in general. See [Ismael Juma's blog post on the subject.](http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/10/14/32-bit-or-64-bit-jvm-how-about-a-hybrid/) For Sun JVMs this means adding `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` to your JVM args in the eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making sure you're using a 64bit JVM. Other than that, there should be no special settings needed.