# Aptana failed to create jvm in windows XP

Tags: jvm, aptana

I am trying to install Aptana studio 3 on a winXP machine.Alothough it has Java installed (verified by java -version in command line) when I run Aptana it says : Failed to create Java Virtual Machine and program exits.

Searching the web seems this is a common problem and .ini file has to be changed maybe? Anyone has a successful experience?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the perfect tweaks as of yet, but I did manage to get it to run and delay its crashes by reading a few good answers related to Eclipse here:

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse#144349)

And this (though it's about win7 64):

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse on windows 7 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007869/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Which led me to this:

http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/10/14/32-bit-or-64-bit-jvm-how-about-a-hybrid/

You need to go into the AptanaStudio3 directory and change the AptanaStudio3.ini file to JVM settings that work better for your system and version of JRE.  For someone like me, and I'm guessing you, who has no Java coding background, this is extremely unintuitive.  So it's pretty much necessary to follow a guide and since there don't seem to be aptana-specific guides, it's best to follow along with the eclipse ones, since aptana is built off the eclipse code base.

I'd try in particular to change the settings, e.g. "-Xmx", "-Xms" and who knows, maybe even try the "--XX:+UseCompressedOops" (not an 'answer' just seems to have worked for some other stackoverflow users, though on different windows configs).